# How make child process with same environment variables as parrent plus it's own in windows?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, environment-variables

In windows for creating new child proccess I'm using `CreateProcess` function:

```
BOOL WINAPI CreateProcess(
  __in_opt     LPCTSTR lpApplicationName,
  __inout_opt  LPTSTR lpCommandLine,
  __in_opt     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
  __in_opt     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
  __in         BOOL bInheritHandles,
  __in         DWORD dwCreationFlags,
  __in_opt     LPVOID lpEnvironment,
  __in_opt     LPCTSTR lpCurrentDirectory,
  __in         LPSTARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
  __out        LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
);
```

Here we can see that `CreateProcess` can get `lpEnvironment` parameter to specify environment variables of new process and if it's NULL, the child will have same environment as parrent. Now I want the child to have same environment as parrent plus environment vars specified in `lpEnvironment` (i.e. merged environment of parent process and specified ones). How would you suggest to do this? Should I take all envs of parent, merge them with new ones and pass them all to `CreateProcess`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [getenv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tehxacec%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get crt env add your own and set

Comment: But how can I use getenv() if I don't know what envs are exists in fact?

Comment: The return value is NULL if varname is not found in the environment table. If you are interested in a specific value, tokenize and compare

Comment: I'm interested in getting all envs. In this case I don't think getenv will help me.

Comment: GetEnvironmentStrings should help (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683187(v=vs.85).aspx). Read remarks

Answer (score 4):

I think you are on the right track. Get existing env block, append your new stuff, pass it to CreateProcess function, then destroy the new env block.

To get current block use [GetEnvironmentStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Appending new variables you will probably have to do by simple string manipulations. The environment block is simply concecutive sequence of null-terminated strings, with double null at the end, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You might want to check first if you are appending new env variable or updating existing one, in case if it is already defined.