# How to call system() in an opened administrator program and gives it the same privileges?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7

I am writing a c++ application in Windows that runs as administrator. However, while calling the `system()` command, it seems that the command doesn't have admin privileges (can't create file in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\` directory).

How can I avoid using [CreateProcess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591183/how-make-child-process-with-same-environment-variables-as-parrent-plus-its-own) ?

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use `system()`? if its just create a file you can use file IO perfectly fine. What are you actually using this command for?

Comment: I am using adb pull, and it is only for self use.

Comment: Saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418791/requesting-administrator-privileges-at-run-time ? Might help you. And also consider this: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/

Comment: Why do you need to avoid using the proper API call?

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that an elevated process will start another process not elevated. How would the implementation of `system` actually achieve that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `CreateProcess` doesn't actually allow you to request elevation. You can do it with the `runas` verb to `ShellExecute`, or with a manifest. But not through `CreateProcess`.

Comment: I think your problem is elsewhere.  Please show us the code that is calling `system()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use [`system`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx) you can use:

```
system("runas /user:<admin-user> \"program.exe\"");
```

Or [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
ShellExecute(hwnd, "runas", "program.exe", 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

[This Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586139/how-to-run-application-which-requires-admin-rights-from-one-that-doesnt-have-th)
details the `CreateProcess` method pretty well.