# How to run cmd commands as an administrator on C++

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

I want to make a program that runs a command in cmd, but as an administrator, But i'm having hard time understanding how to do it.

I've tried changing my program startup properties to start as an administrator but it still didn't work, when i called system() it wasn't administrator.

I tried this this solution which I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523829/how-to-call-system-in-an-opened-administrator-program-and-gives-it-the-same-pr)

```
system("runas /user:<admin-user> \"program.exe\"");
```

But i dont undertand how am i suppose to run commands with it like:

```
system("runas /user:<admin-user> \" COMMAND HERE? \"");
```

when I tried running the solution in cmd i got error saying the file specific as not found

In addition i am trying to do this project avoiding CreateProcess.
Thank you

Comment: what have you tried on `\" COMMAND HERE? \"` ?

Comment: @Coursal this was an example of what i dont understand, where to put the command

Comment: Put the command in place the ` COMMAND HERE? ` part of the string.

Comment: do you mean at what line in the source code? do you mean what to put instead of `\" COMMAND HERE? \"`?

Comment: @Coursal I mean how to use it to run commands, look at my first code example

Comment: What commands are you wanting to run? Any command you type in `cmd.exe` can be passed to `system()` as it just runs `cmd.exe` with the command. But why are you using `system()` to run commands? Chances are, there is usually a better direct API for most commands

Comment: @KamilCuk when i do it i get an error "The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: What you do what? When you do `system("runas /user:<admin-user> \"program.exe\"");` ? What if you open a comand line and put the exact same command in your command line? Try `printf("runas /user:<admin-user> \"program.exe\"");` and copy the exact output to the command line window and try it.

Comment: That means the executable you are trying to run is not a valid file name or the folder for it is not in the PATH environment variable. Also I believe run-as will inherit the environment (and drives mapped) as the user you run-as not the current user's environment. One way to check this is to run a cmd.exe window as the user and see if the command works in the cmd.exe window.

Comment: C++ has no notion of an admin user.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to make your own `system`. Something like this may suffice:

```
BOOL RunAsAdmin( LPCTSTR lpFile, LPCTSTR lpParameters, HWND hWnd ) {
    BOOL                retval;
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO    sei;
    ZeroMemory ( &sei, sizeof(sei) );

    sei.cbSize          = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    sei.hwnd            = hWnd;
    sei.fMask           = SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT | SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;
    sei.lpVerb          = TEXT("runas");
    sei.lpFile          = lpFile;
    sei.lpParameters    = lpParameters;
    sei.nShow           = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    retval = ShellExecuteEx( &sei );
    // or try as the normal user ... remove if that's not an option
    if( !retval ) {
        sei.lpVerb = TEXT("open");
        retval = ShellExecuteEx( &sei );
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: Why are you mixing LPTSTR with plain strings? Use `TEXT()` on those strings or force Unicode.

Comment: @Anders Fair point. I think i got them all.

Comment: No, you messed up again. LPCTSTR+TEXT or LPCWSTR+L+ShellExecuteExW

Comment: @Anders In context,  what I had would work, but I agree on the sloppyness. New try. I left the `W` out on the `ShellExecuteEx` on pupose. If that fails - problems.

Comment: You can make it work everywhere regardless of the UNICODE setting. Failing to compile is a distant 2nd I guess.

Comment: @Anders I don't know if what it'd take to make it unicode proof is required to answer questions - but isn't this an answer to OP:s question as it stands?

Comment: Yes, anyone with a little bit of win32 experience can make this code work regardless of their UNICODE setting. But SO answers should aim for perfection (IMHO) which is why I made a comment.

Comment: @Anders You are welcome to make any edits you'd like to my answer or to provide an answer yourself. Please do, because I'm doubting myself at this point.

Comment: There is nothing to doubt. Pasting this into a Unicode project will work without changes. Ansi projects will require minor modifications. Your initial answer was so close but you commented out the `_TEXT` macro for some reason.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's literally the only answer I could find online on this matter. How ShellExecuteEx manages to execute the passed cmd as admin? The params here are quite not self evident.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be using [`CreateProcessAsUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasusera), but based on your wish to avoid `CreateProcess`, you probably don't want to use that either.

To do it with `system`, you want to create a string that contains the complete command to execute, then pass that to `system`, something on this general order:

```
void run_program(std::string const &admin_name, std::string const &cmd) { 
    std::strings buffer = "runas /user:" + admin_name + " " + cmd;

    system(buffer.c_str());
}
```

Comment: This does not  UAC elevate which is probably what the OP wants.